# python mysql connector adds unnecessary precision value to a float data type cell having an integer value

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

I have a table in which there is a column "column_float" which is of data type float but the value inserted for this column is an integer value 5

When I read this value through python mysql connector it gives me a float value 5.0

My requirement is that if an integer value is there in the float column it should be read as an integer only without adding any extra precision.

Any help here ? Any settings for python mysql connector to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point have always decimals, but you can check if it has any and then round only when there is only a zero.

Replace the @a with your column name

```
SET @a = 5.0;
SELECT IF( ROUND(@a,0) = @a,ROUND(@a,0),@a)
```

Result

```
# IF( ROUND(@a,0) = @a,ROUND(@a,0),@a)
5
```

And form any other like

```
SET @a = 5.1;
SELECT IF( ROUND(@a,0) = @a,ROUND(@a,0),@a)
```

Result

```
# IF( ROUND(@a,0) = @a,ROUND(@a,0),@a)
5.1
```

For python there a there same functions

```
round(5.0)
# Returns: 5
```

Comment: Thanks @nbk , but my issue is more inclined towards mysql connector, in my code I am fetching data through select * from table , so I want to know if there is anything at mysql-connector global setting so that it doesn't add extra precision by itself.

Comment: If you have a mixed column wiith float and Integer, and you don't want to use python to Round your values. Besides SELECT *  is very bad programming, because you always should minimize the data volume and only SELECT the columns that you need. So roung in mysql or python it is your choice